# Removing a number of pixels of an image

Tags: java, bufferedimage, pixel

- Pre: Receives a buffered image and a number of pixels to remove

  - Post: creates and returns a copy of the received image with the given number of the images remaining pixels removed

I am having trouble with this method because I need to remove random pixels...I have only made a new copy of the image to print, but I need to change it so that the number of pixels given are removed...can anyone help?

```
public static BufferedImage removePixels(BufferedImage img,int numToRemove)
{
      //so far what I have gotten
    BufferedImage copy =  new BufferedImage(img.getWidth(), img.getHeight(), BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
    copy.getGraphics().drawImage(img, 0,0,null);


    return copy;
}
```

Comment: I forgot...the pixels are actually just removed by setting them transparent...

Comment: I would start by using `Math.random()` to find random pixel coordinates and set them transparent. Maybe use a for loop to control how many times this happens, with an ArrayList to keep track of pixels that have already been removed?

Answer (score 0):

`bufferedImage.setRGB(int x , int y , int rgb)` and `bufferedImage.getRGB(int x , int y)` might be what you're looking for.